# Pointer to a pointer in a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Hey guys I'm having a little difficulty understanding how to have a pointer point to another pointer in a struct, that thereby points to another pointer in a struct. Not sure if that makes sense.

Basically, usually I would write something like:

```
test->first = NULL;
```

But I need to access a part of first as well. I am trying:

```
test->first->alpha = NULL;
```

But that isn't working. Any ideas on how I can access the alpha by only declaring test? And thereby set test->first->alpha to NULL?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to declare structs like this, here's an example:

```
 struct First {
     int alpha;
 };
 struct Test {
     struct First* first;
 };
```

As others have pointed out, you must make sure test->first points somewhere before you try to dereference it, like so:

```
struct Test* test = malloc(sizeof(struct Test));
test->first = malloc(sizeof(struct First));
test->first->alpha = 123;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you assign a valid pointer to `test->first` you can't access `test->first->alpha`. If you do anyway, you dereference an invalid pointer and that leads to undefined behavior and a probably crash.

Answer (score 0):

If `first` it self is pointing to `NULL`, then accessing `alpha` on it leads to undefined behavior.

Make sure `first` points to valid memory location and then you can assign it's members.